# VBA code to delete rows only deletes first row

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to VBA and I'm trying to delete 8 rows based on a cell value I find and save a reference to earlier in the code.  Earlier in the code I find where "totalCell" is based on a do until loop. It definitely finds the right cell, but the loop below seems to only delete one row (the totalCell row).

```
   ' Loop to delete "total" section of spreadsheet
    Dim totalCell As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 8
        totalCell.EntireRow.Delete
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Set totalCell = ActiveCell
    Next i
```

It is only deleting the first row where the totalCell reference is, then no other rows seem to be deleted.  I added in that "ActiveCell.Offset(1,0) section because I thought that after I deleted where totalCell was it would delete the reference to that cell as well.

Any guidance as to why it's not deleting other rows would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: A simple `totalCell.Resize(8).EntireRow.Delete` should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try that first thing tomorrow!